# spyder editor is it possible to set autocomplete to Tab?

Tags: autocomplete, spyder

I'm trying to set autocomplete functionality in spyder editor to Tab via 
Tools --> preference --> KeyBoardShortcuts.

in the popup, window tab is used as the toggle switch. so i cant set the Tab as shortcut key. please help to set Tab as autocomplete key.

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is defined by default to get completions in the Editor, so you don't need to set it through our Preferences.

Besides, this functionality is hard-coded in our source code, so you can't reassign <kbd>Tab</kbd> to something else.

Comment: thanks for responding. I'm using Spyder 3.2.6 in this version Tab key is used for 4 spaces (indentation). please let me know if I'm wrong or I'm using the different version.

Comment: You have to press `Tab` next to a word to get completions. If you press it in an empty line, at the beginning of a line or next to characters that don't admit completion (e.g. `:`) then `Tab` would insert 4 spaces, as you mentioned.